# What does the phrase “À quoi rêvent les personnes qui nous font vivre ce monde ?” mean?

Tags: sens, pronoms

The phrase is from the song "Remède" by Mass Hysteria - full lyrics available here: https://www.paroles-musique.com/eng/Mass_Hysteria-Remede-lyrics,p5760

Google translate offers up "What are the people who make us live this world dream?" and I have a sneaking suspicion that this is not exactly the right interpretation.

I'm an absolute beginner to French by the way.

Comment: It means "what do the people who make us live this world dream of?" - which, in the abstract, is quite cryptic even for a French speaker.

Comment: @guillaume31 Merci pour la réponse! Cryptic indeed!

Comment: That's not quite right either, I think. There's some inversion going on. "What do those who bring the world to life for us dream of?"

Comment: @LukeSawczak yes, both interpretations are correct. I don't know much about this in the specific context though.

Comment: @LukeSawczak ah ok, I was wondering if there was more to it like that, merci aussi!

Comment: Np... I'll come back to this soon and (if someone else hasn't already done so) I'll write a bit more on it as an answer

Comment: @LukeSawczak Couldn't “ce monde” be “this world” as in “this type of strange world that is described in the song”? I'd perceive it somewhat near what guillaume31 said, actually. Except I don't think it's that cryptic...

Comment: @Montéedelait I think that's valid as to "monde", and I agree there's at least ambiguity about the syntax. But how normal is "vivre + COD" where the COD isn't une vie, un temps, ou une expérience ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak In an everchanging world, we could, I suppose, LIVE + a certain type of world. Also, perhaps, “une réalité”.

Comment: @Montéedelait That seems possible, but I think we'll need a different English word then. "Live this world" is a little too unexpected. And reading the lyrics, I'm still thinking that these people who rayonnent, with whom we're not alone, might be making this world alive for us.

Comment: @LukeSawczak There is without a doubt the idea that “this world” is “fourmillant de millions d’hommes et de femmes”. Perhaps there is some sense of helplessness in trying to figure out what the exact nature of so many dreams is: we'll either find some general trends of dreams, or we'll miss out altogether on a lot of dreams if we stop and analyse a few in more details.

Comment: Sur [Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22vivre%20un%20monde%22%29&lang=en&suggest=0). Tous ne conviennent pas comme illustration de "vivre un monde" tel que nous en discutons, mais certains sont indéniablement dans cette veine.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: If you're going to make an answer I think this *nous* can be considered as an expletive (as in for example *Tu nous le fous à la poubelle !*) Maybe it'll help to find more references.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps the idiomaticity of this sentence is beyond me after all.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: Now, I think some call it more precisely “datif éthique”, with the purpose of throwing in witnesses.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Now that I think about it some more, I really wonder who those people are that “make us live this world”. Until now, I thought they were those millions mentioned elsewhere in the song, but could it also be some sort of godly entities external to “this world”? Now, I'd really like to read the analysis of someone who knows Mass Hysteria well.

Comment: @Montéedelait from what I have seen there is an element of Rastafari language and culture in Mass Hysteria's songs hence the "I and I will never feel alone" - "I and I" being a reference to the oneness of God and the person who believes in Him, Rastafari believing as they do in God residing within the person. Perhaps this sheds some light on the symbolism in this song and perhaps this phrase? I did not expect such a lively discussion on this question!

Comment: Songs and poetry in general can be amongst the hardest pieces of wording around, and their meanings commonly escape us at the first glance or even the second time around. La Fontaine's Fables are a great example of how delicately yet simply carven they can be. Reading or hearing them twenty or a hundred times eventually allows the reader/hearer to grasp so many exquisite details about them. I'm not that surprised a song generates this kind of discussion, actually. It's been seen before (look at Luke's past questions for some great examples...).

Comment: @Montéedelait very true - I've seen the same in German and Irish, and of course English. Many thanks for the responses! merci à tous pour les réponses!

Comment: @DarraghJ: From your explaination, I am now convinced that grammatically it's a simple causative construction, with (at the very least for me) an unexpected meaning, which is built on top a rare expression, as Montée de lait explains below in his answer. It's not what I previously deemed more likely, not knowing about the context, although grammatically I was considering both options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>I’m going to chance an answer, but I offer no guarantee that it is the right one. It is based on my understanding of the lyrics. The words or grammatical structure, as far as I’m concerned, were not an issue, but the overall meaning of the song remained elusive, and was partly clarified by the person asking. So this was my disclaimer. Onward to the answer now.</sup>

---

**First verse**

The first one claim we can dramatically change our lives *(our life and its vibe)*, though we may rightly doubt it *(which force could make us believe it?)*. However, the consequence of ignoring temptation *(to zip by it without stopping)* is that we shall regret it later in life *(these are the things, apparently, that haunt us later)*.

**The millions**

The description of the source of so much temptation in life: millions of other people like us, around us, men and women showing their Humanity every second.

The last line is a bit confusing for me, but has been clarified by the person asking, so I’ll stick to it. It is part of the Rastafari language and culture, embraced by Mass Hysteria. *“I and I”* refers to the oneness of God and the person believing in Him. Thus, I suppose, we are human, but also divine through God being within us. So *“I and I”* refers to me and God within me, and this person is awed by the multitude, and is feeling part of that multitude and cannot imagine ever feeling alone with so many interesting people and vibe around.

**À quoi rêvent les personnes qui nous font vivre ce monde ?**

A question arose when I tried to identify precisely who are *the persons who make us live this world*.

But what is this world anyway to begin with ? In English, according to Luke Sawczak, we can live a life or an experience, but to live a world would be unexpected. Though it is not the most commonly used complement to the verb in French either, it is nevertheless [attested](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22vivre%20un%20monde%22%29&lang=en&suggest=0), and it is by no mean shocking to the French ear. Here are a few examples from the litterature :

> Il est une onde pure, il est une clarté
> Que la terre, aujourd'hui, refuse obstinément ;
> Il ne vaut pas de **vivre un monde** sans beauté
> Sans honneur, sans amour, mort, rongé par l'argent.
> <sub>—*Coffrets étoilés*, André Lebey, 1918</sub>
>
> Va donc, autour de moi, l'homme chétif et blême,
> Magnifique Univers, suis ton cours triomphal !
> Tu ne m'écrases pas. Dès qu'il pense et qu'il aime,
> Fier d'écouter aussi **vivre un monde** en lui-même,
> L'atome te regarde et se sent ton égal !
> <sub>—Georges Lafenestre (1837-1919)</sub>
>
> Elle révèle, note Brook, « **une manière de vivre un monde** en situation de catastrophe sans perdre contact avec ce qui permet à l'homme de vivre et de se battre d’une manière positive ».
> <sub>—Jean Mambrino, 1985</sub>

So this world that *“we live”* is simply the world as described in other parts of the song, that is, the world of millions, where temptation arises, and where *“I and I will never feel alone”*.

But who is or who are the instigators of this world, the persons making us “live this world”?

The answer is not simple. Based on the oneness of God, discussed earlier, I would conclude we are not looking at those beings outside of this world that created it but are separated from it altogether. Therefore, these persons are most likely the “millions d’hommes, de femmes”, qui “rayonnent” de “millions d’ondes en chaque seconde”. They inhabit the World, and that world would exist without them, but **that world** would not become **this world** without them actively shaping it the way it is. There’s a sense of synergy in the statement, but also a sense of the individual actors being one and one, being individuals that remain somewhat mysterious to “I and I” *(aren’t we on a “collision-filled trajectory”, after all?)*, provocking the questionning: “What are THEY dreaming of?”.

Is the translation necessary after this? I don’t feel it will do justice to the line in particular, since it takes its full meaning within the context, for which I offered one possible explanation here above. So please excuse me for not supplying one.

---

<sub>Well, shortly after deciding not to supply a translation, [Stéphane Gimenez](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/79) proposed one in the comments below that seemed acceptable and fair to me, and allowed me to cite it. So here it is:</sub>

#### What do those who make us experience this world dream of?

<sub>The translation came with the following comments, that are just as carefully cautious as mine :~)</sub>

> <sub>It isn't perfect but at least “experience” is something neutral between “enjoy” and “endure”. Now to narrow the gap, one can try to think about the difference between “experiencing” and “living” outside of any context, as unfortunately “live a world” is not quite idiomatic.</sub>